# How to securely upload and display images in PHP

Tags: php, security

I'm writing a functionality in an web app which will allow users to upload images which will be rendered in pages. The images will be uploaded via rich text area editor, similar to the UI here in stackoverflow.

Users uploading and displaying images makes me feel uneasy. I know that a lot of hacks exploit the file upload functionality. I want to secure my app as best as possible.

The app is written in PHP, but I don't think the language matters that much. What is important are the steps taken in the process of uploading and displaying the file.

Here is what I'm planning to implement:

1. Users upload file
2. Check file size >= MAX_FILE_SIZE (let's say 2MB)
3. Check mime type (image/jpeg, image/png) to allow only jpeg and png images.
4. Generate random filename for the uploaded file with the extension from the mime type.
5. Store file
6. Display image

One thing immediately pops in my mind. Is it possible somehow to trick the function used to determine the mime type so that you can upload other than image?

Another thing is, I'm using a PHP framework (Symfony) which has a catch all route controller, which means the web server first tries to locate the requested file on the disk, and if it doesn't exist then it forwards the request the to catch all. So the whole security responsibility should be in the web server and not in the PHP app since the request will be forwarded to the web server.

It seems that the web server behaviour is the most important thing? And the web server is out of the application logic. The web server I'm using is nginx.

So my question is, are these steps enough the secure my app? Is there any more steps I can implement to secure it even more?

Comment: I would check and convert the files with something like [ImageMagick](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php). Use [Imagick::valid()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.valid.php) to check the validity. This will only accept images. Converting them before storage, to be usable for displaying, also means that any nasty payload will be removed. This still leaves you with the problem of the content of the images. There are certainly images that are illegal to store and serve. The whole idea to allow anonymous users to upload images is flawed.

Comment: As to security, I'd recommend storing images in a location that cannot execute PHP code at all. In fact, although a little bit more work, I'd probably create a dedicated non-PHP site using a subdomain just for this purpose. The images would be uploaded into the PHP site, but stored on the non-PHP site. The non-PHP site can then server true 404s as needed without accidentally routing to Symfony.

Comment: No anonymous users will be able to upload images, it’s a typo. Sorry for the confusion. @ChrisHaas

Comment: Yes, **of course it's possible**, but **how does it matter**? I think you should make your mind on what you call a "file type" and why it's important.

Comment: Regarding web-server part, all you need to know is that your server determines the file type based on its *extension*. Provided your files will have only image-related extensions, web-server will serve them as images.